# react-native-multiple-select storing items selected on submit

Tags: arrays, react-native, multi-select

I am using react-native-multiple-select and trying to create a dropdown menu that allows users to select multiple options and then logs the options they select into an array. 
At the moment, my code is:

```
    onSelectedItemsChange = selectedItems => {
    this.setState({ selectedItems });
    console.log('submit button was pressed')
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedItems } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <MultiSelect
          hideTags
          items={items}
          uniqueKey="id"
          ref={(component) => { this.multiSelect = component }}
          onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChange}
          selectedItems={selectedItems}
          selectText="Pick Items"
          searchInputPlaceholderText="Search Items..."
          onChangeInput={ (text)=> console.log(text)}
          altFontFamily="ProximaNova-Light"
          tagRemoveIconColor="#CCC"
          tagBorderColor="#CCC"
          tagTextColor="#CCC"
          selectedItemTextColor="#CCC"
          selectedItemIconColor="#CCC"
          itemTextColor="#000"
          displayKey="name"
          searchInputStyle={{ color: '#CCC' }}
          submitButtonColor="#CCC"
          submitButtonText="Submit"
        />
        <View>
```

The problem is with the submit button. I only want to record the items selected once the user has pressed submit.

At the moment it logs that the button was pressed every time a new item is selected and that does not help with storing the items selected into another array.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to get an array with the item objects that are selected:

```
for(var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++){
this.state.selectedItemsArray.push(this.state.gasOptions[selectedItems[i]])
}
console.log(selectedItems);
```

This should output the array of items that are selected with each item containing the unique key and the display name.

Comment: In fact this is setting state after each checkbox is checked. How can you set state only after Submit button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.selectedItemsArray.push(listOfObject[0].id);`

I noticed that the `selectedItemsArray` stores only the key so its an array of keys and not list of objects. Thus, if your key is `id` you want to push that to the array and not all the object.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue before. Now I fixed it.
Follow below steps:

1. Go to **node_modules/react-native-multi-select/index.d.ts**  add the code

`onSubmitclick: ((items: any[]) => void),` inside export interface MultiSelectProps {}

[image]

2. Go to **lib/react-native-multi-select.js** add the code

`onSubmitclick: PropTypes.func,`  inside the static propTypes ={}

[image]

3. Go to the function **_submitSelection()** and add the code inside it

   `const {selectedItems, onSubmitclick } = this.props; onSubmitclick(selectedItems);`

[image]

4. Now you return your Multiselect tag add

`onSubmitclick={(value1) => getSubmit(value1)}`

[image]

5. capture your selected value with this function

`const getSubmit = (value1) => { console.log('new submit value***', value1) }`

Comment: Getting Item Twice after making above changes!