# React-native-multiple-select get items on submit

Tags: react-native, drop-down-menu, picker, multiple-select

I am using `react-native-multiple-select` and its working, however, what I would like to do is to get all selected items **AFTER** I **SUBMIT** and not while I am selecting.

```
<MultiSelect
      hideTags
      items={this.filter_pref}
      uniqueKey="id"
      ref={(component) => { this.multiSelect = component }}
      onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChange}
      selectedItems={selectedItems}
      selectText="Zgjedh "
      searchInputPlaceholderText="Kerko filterat..."
      // onChangeInput={(text) => console.log(text)}
      altFontFamily="ProximaNova-Light"
      tagRemoveIconColor="#CCC"
      tagBorderColor="#CCC"
      tagTextColor="#CCC"
      selectedItemTextColor="#CCC"
      selectedItemIconColor="#CCC"
      itemTextColor="#000"
      displayKey="name"
      searchInputStyle={{ color: '#CCC' }}
      submitButtonColor="#CCC"
      submitButtonText="Zgjedh"
      />
```

And the function where I set the values:

```
 onSelectedItemsChange = selectedItems => {

        this.setState({ selectedItems });
}
```

Comment: cant you just set it to state  this.setState({  selectedItems: selectedItems    });

Comment: @obumoon I am already doing that, please check my code.

Comment: did you try calling selectedItems from state after ? if so what did you get? also are you navigating to a different page after submit

Comment: @obumoon The problem is that it sets the state after each checkbox is checked (not after submit). I want it to set state ONLY after I press SUBMIT. I am not navigating to another page, I just want to set state after submit button is pressed, and after that I am using the data from that state on a flatlist.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Is there any solution ?

Comment: This solution solved my issue @BMX         https://stackoverflow.com/a/70286032/11752083

Comment: These steps solved my problems. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70286032/11752083 I hope, it will help someone.